# TPM tools show incorrect size

Tags: tpm

I have installed tpm tools from Ubuntu. the version is 1.3.7 
using tpm_nvinfo.

```
root@test-hardware-1:/home/tseng/trousers-0.3.13# tpm_nvinfo
NVRAM index   : 0x10000001 (268435457)
PCR read  selection:
PCR write selection:
Permissions   : 0x00000000 ()
bReadSTClear  : FALSE
bWriteSTClear : FALSE
bWriteDefine  : FALSE
Size          : 0 (0x0)

NVRAM index   : 0x1000f000 (268496896)
PCR read  selection:
PCR write selection:
Permissions   : 0x00000000 ()
bReadSTClear  : FALSE
bWriteSTClear : FALSE
bWriteDefine  : FALSE
Size          : 0 (0x0)

NVRAM index   : 0x50000003 (1342177283)
PCR read  selection:
PCR write selection:
Permissions   : 0x00000000 ()
bReadSTClear  : FALSE
bWriteSTClear : FALSE
bWriteDefine  : FALSE
Size          : 0 (0x0)

NVRAM index   : 0x50000001 (1342177281)
PCR read  selection:
PCR write selection:
Permissions   : 0x00000000 ()
bReadSTClear  : FALSE
bWriteSTClear : FALSE
bWriteDefine  : FALSE
Size          : 0 (0x0)

NVRAM index   : 0x20000002 (536870914)
PCR read  selection:
PCR write selection:
Permissions   : 0x00000000 ()
bReadSTClear  : FALSE
bWriteSTClear : FALSE
bWriteDefine  : FALSE
Size          : 0 (0x0)

NVRAM index   : 0x40000001 (1073741825)
PCR read  selection:
PCR write selection:
Permissions   : 0x00000000 ()
bReadSTClear  : FALSE
bWriteSTClear : FALSE
bWriteDefine  : FALSE
Size          : 0 (0x0)

NVRAM index   : 0x20000001 (536870913)
PCR read  selection:
PCR write selection:
Permissions   : 0x00000000 ()
bReadSTClear  : FALSE
bWriteSTClear : FALSE
bWriteDefine  : FALSE
Size          : 0 (0x0)
```

It shows incorrect size. Need to update to 1.3.8

Answer (score 0):

See this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1126097). There was a patch added to tpm-tools that broke tpm_nvinfo. Recompiling from source with the recommended patch changes worked for me on RHEL7.